# How to create this tab navigation with the underline with radius

Tags: html, css

im trying to create something like this google tabs menu with this bar with some radius.

[image]

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li a.active {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1a73e8;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="mytasks.htm">My tasks</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried various types of combinations but failed...

Comment: you clearly wanted to style `li a.active::before {` or `li a.active::after {` pseudo-element, not the `li a.active {`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Use the `::after` pseudo on the `.active` anchor
- don't style `li` elements. Treat them as semantic wrappers
- use display: flex on the `.tabs` (yes, use a class for that UL parent)

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.tabs {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  color: #888;
}

.tabs a.active {
  color: #1a73e8;
}

.tabs a.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="mytasks.html" class="active">My tasks</a></li>
  <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
  <li><a href="prifile.html">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have tried to solve your problem using some CSS code changes. try it:

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
li a{
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
}
li a.active{
  color: green;
}
li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="mytasks.htm">My tasks</a></li>
  </ul>
```